# Como descobrir a porta do servidor que respondeu a requisição

Tags: node.js, proxy

Estou usando o [http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) para criar um load balancer em NodeJS, neste módulo tem o evento

```java
proxy.on('proxyRes', function (res) {
  ..
});
```

Dentro deste evento, eu gostaria de pegar a porta do servidor que respondeu a requisição pelo parâmetro `res`.

**EDIT**

Enquanto eu depurava executei o método `res.connection.remoteAddress`, no qual depois que executo aparece a propriedade `res.connection._peername`
Agora eu pergunto, esta é a unica forma e a mais correta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não entendi se você está procurando as informações do servidor alvo ou do servidor local.

Se você estiver buscando pela porta utilizada pelo proxy para conectar ao servidor alvo, a melhor maneira realmente é utilizando o método `res.connection._getpeername()`

Se você estiver buscando pela porta utilizada pelo cliente para conectar no proxy, você poderia utilizar a opção `xfwd` do próprio `httpProxy` para enviar o header `x-forwarded` para o servidor alvo.

Assim, quando o servidor alvo responder, você terá no objeto da requisição, as informações.

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
    xfwd: true
});
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://google.com/' });
});

server.listen(80);

proxy.on('proxyRes', function (res) {
    var header = res.req._headers;
    console.log(res.req.connection._getpeername());
    console.log(header['x-forwarded-port']);
});
```

Comment: Utilizei o res.connection._getpeername()